# More efficient way to add lists depending on specified order

Tags: java

I have three different ArrayLists that need to be combined into one, however, their order in the stack is important and specified. How can I go about doing this more efficiently?

What the code is doing is adding the ArrayList to the appropriate level (0,1,2) of the complete ArrayList, but there is so much duplicate code that this method seems horrible.

The ultimate goal is the following--the column that we care about is passed along with the required order to our function. Then, depending on the order, we put it in the appropriate place with the other two columns filling the rest (their order is irrelevant).

So basically, Column3 is passed, for example, with order 2. That means we want the complete ArrayList to be Column1's contents, then Column3's contents, then Column2's contents (where Column1 and Column2 could swap because their order doesn't really matter).

Thanks.

```
public void assemble(List<Card> selection, int order) {

        switch(order) {
            case 0:
                trickDeck.addAll(selection.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                if (selection == column1) {
                    trickDeck.addAll(column2.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    trickDeck.addAll(column3.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                }
                else if (selection == column2) {
                    trickDeck.addAll(column1.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    trickDeck.addAll(column3.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                }
                else {
                    trickDeck.addAll(column1.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    trickDeck.addAll(column2.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (selection == column1) {
                    trickDeck.addAll(column2.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    trickDeck.addAll(selection.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    trickDeck.addAll(column3.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                }
                else if (selection == column2) {
                    trickDeck.addAll(column1.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    trickDeck.addAll(selection.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    trickDeck.addAll(column3.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                }
                else {
                    trickDeck.addAll(column1.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    trickDeck.addAll(selection.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    trickDeck.addAll(column2.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (selection == column1) {
                    trickDeck.addAll(column2.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    trickDeck.addAll(column3.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    trickDeck.addAll(selection.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                }
                else if (selection == column2) {
                    trickDeck.addAll(column1.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    trickDeck.addAll(column3.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    trickDeck.addAll(selection.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                }
                else {
                    trickDeck.addAll(column1.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    trickDeck.addAll(column2.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    trickDeck.addAll(selection.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to pass the actual `List` object as an argument, or can you identify the column numerically?

Comment: I could identify it numerically

Comment: If `column1`, `column2`, and `column3` are all `List<Card>` (and they have to be for `selection == column1` to make any sense), then `trickDeck.addAll(column1.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()))` is the very, VERY, slow way of saying `trickDeck.addAll(column1)`.

Comment: @Andreas, it's certainly better than `column1.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a column index instead of passing in the actual `List`. Then we can manipulate the columns as an array. Here's an untested demonstration:

```
public void assemble(int selection, int position) {
    // create list of columns
    List<List<Card>> columns = Arrays.asList(column1, column2, column3);

    // if selected column is not located at position, swap:
    if (selection != position) {
        List<Card> temp = columns.get(position);
        columns.set(position, columns.get(selection));
        columns.set(selection, temp);
    }

    // add all columns to trickDeck in order
    columns.forEach(trickDeck::addAll);
}
```